# Ionic running on a terminal but not on an other! Under Mac OS

Tags: angular, macos, shell, ionic-framework, terminal

i have the problem that ionic is running without any problem in a Terminal but when i open another terminal the ionic command is not recognized!

I am using the same shell on both terminals.
[image: Left the ionic working terminal window - Right the not working terminal]

Can someone help? Thnks!

Comment: try to close & re-open your Terminal, you might have installed ionic recently & the open instance of Terminal might not be aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this by typing:

```
nvm use node
```